# What exactly happens with new session creation when php + memcache PECL extension 'looses' one of its memcache session servers?

Tags: php, session, memcached

**Quick note, I am not talking about existing session, I know, they will be lost if a memcache server is taken offline.**

---

Imagine the following situation:

a) PHP

b) PECL memcache extension ( http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache )

c) PECL memcache setup as the session handler

d) Multiple memcache servers setup to do this via session.save_path = "tcp:.....**,** tcp:.....";

e) One of the memcache servers goes down (server reboot, daemon stop, etc). So at this point we would still be left with at least one valid, and working, memcache server.

**How does the above affect new sessions being created?**

I have taken a look at the memcache manual at http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.ini.php and the manual is a bit thin.

Although it does say that the same params as listed in http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.addserver.php apply.

We have tried shuting down one of our memcached servers to test and our php log starts to fill with 'unable to write session data, check your....'.

Currently our session.save_path ini setting looks something like:

```
session.save_path = "tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:z?persistent=1, tcp://yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:z?persistent=1";
```

So, to summarize:

1) What happens when one of the session handlers goes down?

2) Is there a way to configure this extension to transparently attempt one of the 'other' memcache servers listed if the attempted one fails? Or is this done automatically?

3) In the memcache runtime config manual pages @ php.net I see a setting "memcache.allow_failover", defaulted to true (on), does this apply to the session handling as well? Or only 'in php' calls to memcache?

Thank you kindly.

---

Further clarification, we are using version 3.0.6 of the extension as located at http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that failover in 3.0.x is broken. I've been trying to work out this for hours and session failover only worked on stable branch (2.2.x). Tried 3.0.5, 3.0.4 and both failed for me.

When using 3.0.6 - it fails silently and doesn't return any error. When using 3.0.4 or 3.0.5 it segfaults and doesn't return any content.

So I'd suggest using your own custom session handler which encapsulates and uses memcache for storing sessions. There you can implement your own failover mechanism.